# Spaces in Email

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to build a GSM Gmail addon that will open a card in the compose window and have several fields and then will generate a template and add it to the email. I have several variables containing HTML content and several containing fields from the card. I have almost gotten that done. The last thing that I need to do is to specify a subject, that will be the same every time, and specify recipients that will be based on a text field in the card.
Here is my code. I have 2 files, one gs code file, and one json manifest file.

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Chicago",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Review Published Email Template",
      "logoUrl": "https://goodbookreviews.page/Logo.png",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "universalActions": [{
        "label": "Book Review ",
        "openLink": "https://www.goodbookreviews.page"
      }]
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [{
        "unconditional": {
        },
        "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
      }],
      "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [{
          "text": "Use Template",
          "runFunction": "onGmailCompose"
        }],
        "draftAccess": "NONE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

code.js:

```
function onGmailCompose(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var header = CardService.newCardHeader()
      .setTitle('Use Template')
      .setSubtitle('Use the template for sending an email after a review has been published.');
  // Create text input for entering the cat's message.
  var input = CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName('email')
      .setTitle('Email')
      .setHint('What is the readers email address?');
  var input2 = CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName('FName')
  .setTitle('First Name')
  .setHint('What is the readers first name?');
  var input3 = CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName('BookTitle')
  .setTitle('Reviewed Book Title')
  .setHint('What is the title of the book reviewed?');
  var input4 = CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName('BookAuthor')
  .setTitle('Reviewed Book Author')
  .setHint('Who is the author of the book reviewed?');
  // Create a button that inserts the cat image when pressed.
  var action = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('useTemplate');
  var button = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Use Template')
      .setOnClickAction(action)
      .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED);
  var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(button);
  // Assemble the widgets and return the card.
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(input)
      .addWidget(input2)
      .addWidget(input3)
      .addWidget(input4)
      .addWidget(buttonSet);
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(header)
      .addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}
function useTemplate(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var email = e.formInput.email;
  var FName = e.formInput.FName;
  var Title = e.formInput.BookTitle;
  var Author = e.formInput.BookAuthor;
  var now = new Date();
  var htmlIntro = '<p>Hello, </p>';
  var html2 = '<p> Thank you for writing a book review at <a href="https://www.goodbookreviews.page">Good Book Reviews</a> on</p>';
  var html3 = '<p>by</p>';
  var html4 = '<p>. You Review has been published to our site. Any personal information you included was NOT published, including first name, last name,  age, and email address. Only info you wrote about the book was published. You can see it right <a href="https://www.goodbookreviews.page./books-and-reviews/look-at-reviews"> here!</a> If you need anything else, feel free to contact us at support@goodbookreviews.page or reply to this email to contact us. <br> Happy Reading,<br> The Book Review Team</p>';
  var message = htmlIntro + FName + html2 + Title + html3 + Author + html4;
  var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
  .setUpdateDraftBodyAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBodyAction()
                            .addUpdateContent(message, CardService.ContentType.MUTABLE_HTML)
                            .setUpdateType(CardService.UpdateDraftBodyType.IN_PLACE_INSERT))
  .build();
  return response;
}
function onGmailMessage(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var header = CardService.newCardHeader()
  .setTitle('Unavailable')
  .setSubtitle('Open the compose window to use template');
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(header);
  return card.build();
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "p" tags create extra newlines. Try something like

```
var htmlIntro = '<p>Hello, ';
var html2 = 'Thank you for writing a book review at <a href="https://www.goodbookreviews.page">Good Book Reviews</a> on ';
var html3 = ' by ';
var html4 = '. You Review has been published to our site. Any personal information you included was NOT published, including first name, last name,  age, and email address. Only info you wrote about the book was published. You can see it right <a href="https://www.goodbookreviews.page./books-and-reviews/look-at-reviews"> here!</a> If you need anything else, feel free to contact us at support@goodbookreviews.page or reply to this email to contact us. <br> Happy Reading,<br> The Book Review Team</p>';
var message = htmlIntro + FName + html2 + Title + html3 + Author + html4;
```

Or, if you use V8 engine, even simpler

```
var message = `<p>Hello, ${FName} Thank you for writing a book review at Good Book Reviews on ${Title} by ${Author}. Your Review has been published to our site. Any personal information you included was NOT published, including first name, last name, age, and email address. Only info you wrote about the book was published. You can see it right here! If you need anything else, feel free to contact us at support@goodbookreviews.page or reply to this email to contact us.</p>
<br>
<p>Happy Reading,</p>
<br>
<p>The Book Review Team</p>
`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked so well. Can you also tell me how I can specify A subject and recipients? I want the subject to be the same every time. But I want the recipients to be based on the info entered in a text field in the card. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, but you should probably post another question for that. Stack rules clearly define - one issue, one question. Maybe someone else would help with this.

Comment: I have done a little more work in the Google API console. I don't need to use the email field or a subject. Check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962709/my-gsm-gmail-addon-does-not-show-the-card